# Tarantool docker build issue: libprofiler.so

Tags: tarantool

I simply started `docker build .` after cloning github `tarantool/docker` repository and got the error message:

```
cp: can't stat '.libs/libprofiler.so*': No such file or directory
```

This error is reproduced for every container version that I tried to build from 1.9 to 2.1. So I think I've stumbled on some well-known problem (?).

My docker version is:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in line endings. Setup your git client to not change line endings to `CRLF` if you're working with cross-platform projects.

Workaround in this particular case: go to `gperftools_alpine.diff`, change all line endings to `LF`, rerun the build.